# How to position vector image in RecyclerView item template

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to adjust the alignment of the menu dots in the `RecyclerView` item so that it's positioned exactly underneath the overflow dots in the Toolbar (i.e. in its original place where it should be)? I tried adjusting the item weights but that didn't work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/rvitem_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="90"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="More options"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vertical"
        android:background="@null"
        android:tint="?attr/colorOverflow"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/rvitem_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_title"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />
```

**Current result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@MacaronLover, The approach you are taking to make the view align by assigning the `weight` seems to be in the right direction. I have taken your xml file and made some adjustments here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingStart="16dp"
  android:paddingTop="8dp"
  android:paddingEnd="8dp"
  android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstImage"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    tools:background="#000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/titleText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      tools:text="Title A" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/subTitleText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      tools:text="Subtitle A" />
  </LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/secondImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_vertical_dots" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The idea here is to aligh our view with the `toolbar`'s padding. By default, the toolbar sets `16dp` padding on start and end. 
So, to start with in our view, we set `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` to be `16dp`. Now, to adjust vertical padding, we set that to `8dp` as it adjusts with the top and below items. Set, the `orientation` of parent to `horizontal`.
Then, we add first `ImageView` and sets its layoutWidth/Height to the values we want.
Then add the `LinearLayout` that holds the two `TextView`s and set it's `orientation` to `vertical` and `layout_width` to `0dp` and add the two child TextViews.
Then finally add the overflow `ImageView` and provide the attributes. Since we set the first image and last image dimensions as static values, when the view is drawn, the width is allocated to these first and the remaining of the width goes to the textview container LinearLayout.
If we note at the pre-view attached, there might seem to be a bit more padding at the end. It is due to the `dot` image src we are assigning to the second image. It doesn't fill the ImageView and hence looks like extra padding. We can adjust this by adjusting the `paddingEnd` value of our parent `LinearLayout`.
Please comment if there are any confusions.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[See this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G52N.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title A"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtitle A"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The vertical dots get shifted to the vertical center when they were previously at the top.